# run cypress using tags

Tags: cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am using Cypress (version:10+) + Cucumber+ Typescript. I need to run the test using tags. Also, I tried cypress-tag but it's not working. Is there a way I can run the cypress test using tags without skipping the test?

Answer (score 5):

You can refer to this sample repository for your setup check it here:
https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/tree/master/examples/browserify-ts

in your **cypress.config.ts**

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import { addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
import browserify from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/browserify";

async function setupNodeEvents(
  on: Cypress.PluginEvents,
  config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions
): Promise<Cypress.PluginConfigOptions> {
  await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

  on(
    "file:preprocessor",
    browserify(config, {
      typescript: require.resolve("typescript"),
    })
  );

  // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
  return config;
}

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",
    supportFile: false,
    setupNodeEvents,
  },
});
```

in your **package.json** should contain the following dependencies and important to set cypress-cucumber-preprocessor settings **"filterSpecs: true"** and **"omitFiltered: true"** to run successfully through tags

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "latest",
    "@cypress/browserify-preprocessor": "latest",
    "cypress": "latest",
    "typescript": "latest"
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "filterSpecs": true,
    "omitFiltered": true
  }
}
```

then you can run your feature files like this:

```
cypress run --env tags=@foo
```

Comment: I found the [configuration](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#configuration-overrides) and [tags](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/tags.md) particularly helpful elaborations!

Comment: You can configure this not only in package.json, but also at separate .cypress-cucumber-preprocessorrc.json file

Answer (score 2):

Best solution to it is the Cucumber Cypress preprocessor. I was able run my test using tags without any issue. The problem I faced in Cypress version 10 was the Itegration folder in the Cypress folder structure was renamed to e2e folder. And in Cucumber-Cypress-preprocessor will always look for files in integration folder (which was there in Cypress version less than 10) for searching tags.